# Display selected tags on the browser

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml file containing html tags as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- New XML document created with EditiX XML Editor (http://www.editix.com) at Tue Mar 18 22:41:05 IST 2014 
-->
<html>
<head>
<title>
title1
</title>
</head>

<body>
<fragment id="heading1">
<h1>
Heading 1
</h1>
</fragment>
<fragment id="heading2">
<h2>
Heading 2
</h2>
</fragment>
<fragment id="paragraph1">
<p>
Paragraph 1
</p>
</fragment>
</body>                  
</html>
```

AFAIK, One way to put the xml data onto a browser is to use xsl. But is there a way I can use xsl to put only the selected fragment tags onto a browser window?  Or, do i have to create another xml containing only the required tags and display them on the browser.

Comment: You sample looks (nearly) like HTML to me so the first option you have is to simply style it with CSS and to define `display: none` for those elements you don't want to show. But of course if needed you can also use XSLT to transform the sample, removing elements you don't want to be displayed.

Comment: You can use XPATH in your xsl file to select fragment tags to display. e.g., `<xsl:for-each select="//fragment[@id='heading1']"></xsl:for-each>`

Comment: thank you for ur suggestions. :) For my purpose, I would write all the needed tags to a different file and use xsl to display them.